# InputReader formatting

Tags: java, format, bufferedreader

I am working with multidimensional arrays but I'm stuck.
First line is the number of test cases while the next line reads an `int(N)` and constructs a `N * N grid`. I just need a little help with test cases.
I have done something below...

```
     public static int[][] parseInput(final String fileName) throws Exception {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

            int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            int[][] result = new int[n][n];

            String line;
            int i = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = line.split("");
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                     result[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]);
        }

            i++;
         }

      return result;
   }
```

Just need how to read this sample input

```
3
2
||
..
3
|.|
...
|||
2
|.
.|
```

How do I read in the first line so as to continue reading for the remaining testcases.
E.g above (read in 3 and read in 3 inputs to construct the grid).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Also, please indent your code properly.

Comment: Are you trying to convert | and . to Integer?

Comment: If you don't need to read the grid elements (| and .) as Integers just simply use a `char[][]` array. (I suppose this is a programming competition problem.)

Comment: vidudaya, I actually do need to read the contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this.(I think this is a programming competition problem)
This example for read in standard input. you can use a FileReader (your reader) instead. others are the same.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   solve();
}

public static void solve() throws Exception {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int testcases = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < testcases; ++i) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int[][] result ;

        result = parseInput(reader, n);

        System.out.println("####");
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
            for(int k=0;k<n;++k){
                System.out.print(result[j][k] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("####");
    }
}

public static int[][] parseInput(BufferedReader reader, int n) throws Exception {

    int[][] result = new int[n][n];

    String line;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        line = reader.readLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            result[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
public static void parseInput(final String fileName) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    int test_cnt = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    for(int i = 0; i < test_cnt;i++){
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int[][] grid = parseInput(n, reader);
        //do something for result grid
    }
}

private static int[][] parseInput(int n, BufferedReader reader) throws Exception{
    int[][] result = new int[n][n];
    String line;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n && (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        //String[] tokens = line.split("");
        char[] tokens = line.toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            result[i][j] = (int)tokens[j];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please pay attention. I suppose "|" or "." as some integers, because you declare "int[][] result".